# Python: Does 'in' operator support '*' wildcards?

Tags: python

```
vendor = ' AFL TELECOMMUNICATIONS '
' AFL TELECOM*' in vendor
```

Running this code gives FALSE when I expected it to give TRUE. It seems that the 'in' clause is not seeing the asterix '*' as wild card. Any suggestions how to make this work? Thanks!

Comment: The `in` operator does not support wildcards. You might want to use regular expressions or another text pattern matching. BTW `' AFL TELECOM' in …` might also be a solution if the wildcard is at the end.

Comment: In this case, where the wildcard is at the end of the test string and should match exactly one character, you can do it with `in`: `' AFL TELECOM' in vendor[:-1]` tests that `vendor` has a substring `' AFL TELECOM'` followed by any character (i.e. the substring is not at the end).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Wildcard matching a string in Python regex search](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1996482/wildcard-matching-a-string-in-python-regex-search)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're gonna want to use a regular expression instead.

```
import re

vendor = 'AFL TELECOMMUNICATIONS'

if re.search('AFL TELECOM.*', vendor):
    print("Match")
else:
    print("No Match")
```